# Best way to create cxf REST json-p service to be used by a GWT client

Tags: gwt, servlets, jsonp, cxf, jax-rs

We're implementing a REST api that returns json-p using CXF and Spring. The service should work with a GWT client. The GWT client calls the service using JsonpRequestBuilder. It passes in two function names, one that the response should be wrapped in in case of success and one if it's a failure.

The call url can look something like this: 
http://our.server.com/restservice?parameter=value...parameter=value&_jsonp=success_callback&_jsonp_failure=failure_callback

When an exception is cast by a service (service failure) I'd like to return an HTTP response with status 200 that contains the exception message. The reason I'm not using the standard jsonp interceptors (JsonpPreStreamInterceptor and JsonpPostStreamInterceptor) is that I'd like to wrap the response body in a different function if an exception has been thrown. This is so that my client (built using GWT) can recognise that an error has occured.

I've written a mapper to convert the exception into a response that looks like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import cfpfelles.WebServiceException;

    @Provider
    public class WebServiceExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<WebServiceException> {

        public Response toResponse(WebServiceException arg0) {

            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).
            type("application/x+javascript").
            entity("Exception: " + arg0.getMessage()).
            build();

        }

    }
```

I've got an instream interceptor that stores the success and failure callback names in the exchange parts of the Message object, so that they can be accessed by the output interceptors. It looks like this:

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    String callbackValue = getCallbackValue(message);
    if (!callbackValue.isEmpty()) {
        if (getAcceptType() != null)
        {
            message.put("Accept", getAcceptType());
        }
        message.getExchange().put(CALLBACK_KEY, callbackValue);
    }

    // failure callback value
    String failureCallbackValue = getFailureCallbackValue(message);
    if (!failureCallbackValue.isEmpty()) {
        message.getExchange().put(FAILURE_CALLBACK_KEY, failureCallbackValue);
    }
}
```

I've got a pre-stream interceptor with a handleMessage method that looks like this:

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) message
            .get("HTTP.RESPONSE");
    try {
        response.getOutputStream().write("callback(".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Fault(e);
    }
}
```

I've got a post-stream interceptor with a handleMessage method that looks like this:

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) message
            .get("HTTP.RESPONSE");

    try {
        response.getOutputStream().write(");".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Fault(e);
    }

}
```

In the pre-stream interceptor, I would like to set the callback wrapper, depending on whether an exception has been thrown or not. Unfortunately I can't figure out a way to do this. I can't seem to read the content of the message in the pre-stream interceptor. Neither can I read the HTTP status. Would really appreciate some help with this. Either how to specifically solve my problem or better ways to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason for service to send 200 even in case of exception. I mean the service can return 500 and the message can be parsed by GWT Client.